# Adding directives to simplify ngx-bootstrap modal

Tags: ngx-bootstrap

> This is a suggestion to simplify the basic usages of [ngx-bootstrap modal](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/modals).

The idea is to use 2 directives:

- `bsDismissModal`

  - replaces [bootstrap `data-dismiss="modal"` attribute](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/modals)
  - works with "OK" button too, delaying the modal closing to pre-handle button click event
- `[bsToggleModal]="modalTemplate"`

  - replaces both [bootstrap `data-toggle="modal"` and `data-target="#exampleModal"` attributes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#live-demo)
  - takes the `ng-template` reference as input value

Usage example:

```html
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" [bsToggleModal]="exampleModal">
    Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<ng-template #exampleModal>
    <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" bsDismissModal>×</button>
                    <h5 class="modal-title">Modal title</h5>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    ...
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" bsDismissModal>Cancel</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (bsDismissModal)="save($event)">Save</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</ng-template>
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple approach would be to use the [`BsModalService`](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/modals#bs-modal-service):

#### `DismissModalDirective`

```js
import { Directive, EventEmitter, HostListener,
         Inject, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { DOCUMENT       } from '@angular/common';

import { BsModalService } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal';

@Directive({
    selector: '[dapDismissModal]'
})
export class DismissModalDirective {
    // tslint:disable-next-line:no-output-rename
    @Output('dapDismissModal') modalClosed = new EventEmitter<MouseEvent>();

    private get modalsCount() {
        return this.modalService.getModalsCount();
    }

    constructor(
        private readonly modalService: BsModalService,
        @Inject(DOCUMENT) private readonly document: Document
    ) {}

    @HostListener('click', ['$event'])
    hideModal(click: MouseEvent) {
        this.modalClosed.emit(click);
        if (click.defaultPrevented) {
            return;
        }

        this.modalService.hide(this.modalsCount);

        // Fix BsModalService
        if (this.modalsCount === 0) {
            this.document.body.classList.remove('modal-open');
        }
    }
}
```

- `(dismissModal)="handleClick($event)"` replaces `(click)="handleClick($event)"`, `$event` being the click `MouseEvent`.
- Modal closing can be cancelled when preventing the click: `event.preventDefault();`.

#### `ToggleModalDirective`

```js
import { Directive, HostListener, Input, TemplateRef } from '@angular/core';
import { BsModalService, ModalOptions                } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal';

@Directive({
    selector: '[bsToggleModal]'
})
export class ToggleModalDirective {
    // tslint:disable-next-line:no-input-rename
    @Input('bsToggleModal') content: TemplateRef<any>;
    @Input() bsModalConfig: ModalOptions;

    constructor(private readonly modalService: BsModalService) {}

    @HostListener('click')
    showModal() {
        this.modalService.show(this.content, this.bsModalConfig);
    }
}
```